# Create 5 columns on repeat in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have to create a 5 column grid in Bootstrap 4 to show over 100 images. The code below works ONLY if I have 5 items. How can I go about it?

PS: It must change 2 column grid on mobile screen.

I understand there's a lot of duplicate with correctly marked answer but there's no actual solution to it when I have more than 5 column.

JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/fwg2os0h/

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">
      1
   </div>
   <div class="col">
      2
   </div>
   <div class="col">
      3
   </div>
   <div class="col">
      4
   </div>
   <div class="col">
      5
   </div>
   <div class="col">
      6
   </div>
   <div class="col">
      7
   </div>
   <div class="col">
      8
   </div>
   <div class="col">
      9
   </div>
   <div class="col">
      10
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @IvanKaraman I don't think that really helps...

Comment: @IvanKaraman Dude!

Comment: @ElaineByene each image will be wrapped in column?

Comment: @IvanKaraman This is very much a flexbox question... So the solution actually lies in the CSS.

Comment: @ElaineByene this task isn't for bootstrap, good solution will be using some image grid, like masonry or something similar other solution to create a custom layout...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe, you can set the `min-width` to 20% and that should fix it. At any point of time, this will have a minimum width of `20%`, which will force it to show only 5 a row.

```css
.my-col {
  min-width: 20%;
}
```

And for the mobile support, please use a custom media query to set `min-width: 50%`.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .my-col {
    min-width: 50%;
  }
}
```

**Demos**

Here's how it looks when it's normal.

```css
.my-col {
  min-width: 20%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .my-col {
    min-width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col my-col">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="col my-col">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="col my-col">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="col my-col">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="col my-col">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="col my-col">
    6
  </div>
  <div class="col my-col">
    7
  </div>
  <div class="col my-col">
    8
  </div>
  <div class="col my-col">
    9
  </div>
  <div class="col my-col">
    10
  </div>
</div>
```

When you have less than 5, it will automatically show them justified.

```css
.my-col {
  min-width: 20%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .my-col {
    min-width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col my-col">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="col my-col">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="col my-col">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="col my-col">
    4
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. There's no bootstrap 4 class that supports this out of the box?

Comment: @ElaineByene Nopes, nothing as of now. But this is a complete bespoke custom requirement, and I don't think this kind of solution will be implemented in a framework like this.

Comment: @ElaineByene If we aren't using the Bootstrap's Grid for this, and giving 20% arbitrarily, it will be perfect as we don't have a 5 column layout. It's either 6 column or 4 column as it is based on a 12 column layout.

Comment: btw, found a problem. if I don't have exact 5 items, the width expands to 100%. See the last row here: https://jsfiddle.net/xuL8h5vm/

Comment: @ElaineByene That's what I mentioned here: `When you have less than 5, it will automatically show them justified.` Did you miss that? If you don't want it justified, you can just use `width: 20%` instead of `min-width: 20%`.

Comment: I did that but its not working: https://jsfiddle.net/xuL8h5vm/1/

Comment: @ElaineByene Fixed it here: [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/0pbxzdtv/). Just add `max-width` with the same value too.

Comment: @ElaineByene If you want, I can update my answer to match the output here: [**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/0pbxzdtv/). We just need to add `max-width` with the same value too.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be easiest to add a media query based column width class for 20%...

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .col-sm-five {
        flex: 0 0 20%;
        max-width: 20%;
    }
}


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-five">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-five">
            2
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-five">
            3
        </div>
         ..
     </div> 
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/RRp8uUraZe

Comment: Quick question. This looks nice. But how does this work? Comparing to my solution, which is just setting a `max-width`, should we also set the `flex` property?

Comment: I can't override the core bootstrap function. This would create a lot of problem for other pages.

Comment: Then just rename the `col-sm-2` to something else like `col-sm-five` ... concept is still the same.

Comment: Thank you. I already accepted the other answer but your solution works too. Thank you so much.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman - yep, it works with just max-width too but may vary in width depending on column content

Answer (score 0):

Please check out Bootstrap's docs about [grid systems](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/).

Play around with the numbers to get what you want. col-md- is for tablets or bigger, col-sm- for mobile.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
    6
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
    7
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
    8
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
    9
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
    10
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why did you use `col-sm-5` instead of `col-sm-6`?

Comment: `col-md-2` would create 6 columns instead. I'm looking to create 5 columns.

Comment: Good question. Corrected that now.

Comment: There's nothing in Bootstrap that helps you with that, currently. You'd have to change the flex value of the column to 0 0 20% and give the max-width the same value.